# oh-my-zsh completion on home directory names

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched to zsh from bash, and I'm using oh-my-zsh. There's a completion behaviour I don't want: in any directory, the list of autocompletion candidates seems to include the names of all users' home directories.

I wasn't able to find the right zsh option to disable this behaviour out of the hundreds that exist.

Comment: It might be due to `cdpath`, try unsetting it: `cdpath=()`.

Comment: Doesn't look like the case. I'm using `oh-my-zsh`, and this behaviour disappears when I don't source it. But I'm still wondering which setting is responsible, so I can just turn that one off.

Comment: can you give an example what command and which parameter you try to complete? If you are e.g. in `/home` and have enabled `autocd` this is expected as it is completing a directory.

Comment: @UlrichDangel: Here's the exact behaviour (modulo exact directory names). I'm in my own home directory (say `/home/jogloran`). I want to access a directory `/home/jogloran/apple/banana`, so I type `cd apple/ba<TAB>`. But in addition to the path `apple/banana`, there's a user called `bambi`, and there are two completion candidates: `bambi` and `banana`. Worse, `bambi` comes first in the completion list. If I select `bambi`, I get taken to `~bambi`. I'm not in `/home`, so this isn't expected behaviour, and I've tried `cdpath=()` beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option responsible for this behaviour is `cdable_vars'. It's not enabled by default.

See the [Manual's chapter about Options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

According [to manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Changing-Directories), zsh tries to expand the expression as if it were preceded by a ‘~’.

To unset the CDABLE_VARS option type in shell or add to .zshrc:

```
$ unsetopt cdablevars
```

(Before unsetting the option I had tens of seconds delay on hosts with autofs mounted home folder)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is the combined effect of zsh's `cdable_vars` and `auto_cd` settings. `oh-my-zsh` sets these settings in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh` if you want to get rid of them.