# Why is zsh (oh-my-zsh) completing directories that don't exist?

Tags: zsh, osx, autocomplete, subversion, oh-my-zsh

**UPDATE 3** I've worked out that these annoying autocomplete options are actually *usernames*. I.e. they exist in `/etc/passwd` I have users such as _kadmin_admin and _kadmin_changepw and many others starting with an underscore. This may be specific to OSX.

Oh-my-zsh is autocompleting with these usernames when it can't find any other matches. I tried adding these usernames to the "Don't complete uninteresting users" list in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh`, but that didn't work. I'm not sure why?

Is there anyway to stop oh-my-zsh from autocompleting usernames?

---

I'm getting frustrated by some weird behaviour in either ZSH or oh-my-zsh. I'm not sure which would be causing it.

The autocomplete seems to be searching some weird directories that I don't want it to. They appear to be some SVN directories, that I know nothing about and have no idea why they would be in the path. (I don't even use SVN)

This behaviour only seems to occur if there are no other matches in the current directory - it must then look in some other path that I have no idea about.

**Example:**

*NOTE: There is nothing in my home dir that matches `mi`*

```
→  ~  cd mi<tab>
→  ~  cd _kadmin
```

I.e. it turns `mi` into `_kadmin`. I have no idea why it is matching that directory.

If I try to actually change into that directory, I get an error anyway (as it is not the full directory name):

```
→  ~  cd _kadmin
cd:cd:10: no such file or directory: _kadmin
```

If I keep pressing `<tab>` then it will match the full directory name:

```
→  ~  cd mi<tab><tab><tab>
→  ~  cd kadmin_admin
→  ~_svn
→  ~_svn pwd
/var/empty
```

I have no idea what is going on there. I have no idea what kadmin_admin is. And why when I change into it, why would I now get a directory name of `~_svn`, and then if I `PWD` it shows `/var/empty`

This is my path:

```
/Users/asgeo1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/asgeo1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/asgeo1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/asgeo1/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/php54/bin:/Users/asgeo1/Projects/dotfiles/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Nothing obvious in there that I can see.

Please someone shed some light on this. It's quite frustrating me!

**EDIT:** Seems someone has had a similar issue before:
[Stop tab completion suggesting 'messagebus'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49661/stop-tab-completion-suggesting-messagebus)   There are no answers on there though :(

**UPDATE:** This is the cd function which oh-my-zsh applies:

```
→  ~  which cd
cd () {
    if [[ "x$*" = "x..." ]]
    then
            cd ../..
    elif [[ "x$*" = "x...." ]]
    then
            cd ../../..
    elif [[ "x$*" = "x....." ]]
    then
        cd ../../..
    elif [[ "x$*" = "x......" ]]
    then
            cd ../../../..
    else
            builtin cd "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: This looks like an issue in oh-my-zsh or rvm. One of these is overloading `cd` with a function. Try running zsh without one of them: does the problem persist? What is the `cd` function and where is it coming from? Is there a `CDPATH`?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, it's oh-my-zsh which is using a `cd` function. Have pasted it above. I also ran zsh without oh-my-zsh, and it did not have the same problem. So I think you could be right. There is no CDPATH set either.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @asgeo1? I just recently ran into this myself.

Comment: This solved it for me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181675/27991

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_kadmin` is probably a completer function for the `kadmin` tool - not a directory. If you attempt completion on something that `zsh` can't find as a command, a directory or a valid and known command argument completion, it then starts to offer completion functions as possible expansion candidates. By default, `zsh` comes with a lot of completers, many of which you may not need - there are bundles for AIX, BSD, Cygwin, various Linux distributions, etc, and they all get read and installed into the shell. If you attempt an expansion on something `zsh` can't find, it has all those installed completion functions to offer you instead.

You configure `zsh` not to offer completer functions by putting this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:functions' ignored-patterns '_*'
```

Reload the file and you should no longer be offered completion functions for tools you don't have installed. Have a look at the `zshcompsys` manpage for (a lot) more detail.

**EDIT** *in reply to UPDATE 3*

If `_kadmin` is actually a user account, you can configure `zsh` to not offer it in completions. It seems the approach is to list the user accounts you do want the shell to consider, which limits any names offered only to those listed. The `zstyle` line is something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' users asgeo1 root
```

I think you can list as many users as you like after the `users` tag. The shell will then only offer those users' home directories as possible completions for the `cd` function or builtin.

I don't know why adding the username to the ignored-patterns in the `completion.zsh` file didn't work - did you reload your config after making the change?

Comment: Thanks for the information - I didn't really know anything about zsh autocomplete functions before. I think that oh-my-zsh must be adding some autocomplete functions that I don't need. If I put that line in my `.zshrc` it doesn't appear to do anything though - I have to still disable oh-my-zsh. I'm hoping there is a way in oh-my-zsh to disable certain completion functions (but leave the git one turned on for example)

Comment: I've worked out that _kadmin actually refers to a username on OSX. See edit to question above. Do you know how to make zsh not autocomplete usernames? I'm struggling to understand the zstyle syntax. Cheers.

Comment: Edited my answer to cover this new information. I hope that fixes it for you!

Comment: Yeah, I did reload the config. So not sure why the ignored-patterns didn't work. But your other suggestion works and is a lot cleaner anyway, so thanks for that!